# onSelect returns first param undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a dropdown button with the eventhandler:

```
onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}>
```

However the first param i receive is undefined the second param is Proxy with info about the event. Why is my first param undefined?

```
  private handleSelect(e1, e2) {
    debugger;
    e1;
    console.log(e2);
  }
```

e1 is undefined
e2 holds event details

the event handler is called on select which resides in an arrow function

```
renderRanks = () => {
const { intl } = this.props;

return (
    <DropdownButton bsSize="sm" id="ranks"
      title={"Title"}>
      {this.store.levels.map((pl) =>
        <MenuItem data={pl.Id} key={pl.Number}>{pl.Name}</MenuItem>)}
    </DropdownButton>
)
}
```

Which is being called from my render

```
{this.renderDropdown()}
```

Comment: Your gravatar is somehow offending.

Comment: are you using a native `<select>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSelect` event handler expects eventKey and event as its params. You are declaring `key` *(from react)* but you aren't declaring `eventKey` *(from react-bootstrap)*.

```
<MenuItem data={pl.Id} key={pl.Number} eventKey={pl.Number}>{pl.Name}</MenuItem>)}
```

editing your `MenuItem` populate call as above should then give you `e1` -> eventKey and `e2` -> event in your `handleSelect`

Answer (score 1):

Use onChange event instead. 
your function handleSelect will be like below

```
handleSelect = (event) => {
    const e1 = event.target.value // contains value of select
    const e2 = event // contains event object
}
```